# How to create bar graph with remote server data using volley in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to create bar graph like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaV9R.png)  with mysq database   using volley

I have managed to retrieve data from db and view in text view it work fine but when I try to use those data  to populate bar graph  nothing happen I don’t know what is wrong with it.

My Json:

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","std1":"30","std2":"55","std3":"70","std4":"47","std5":"91","std6":"10","std7":"54"}]}
```

And Below is my entire java  code  I followed the barGraph concept  from  [here](http://www.android-examples.com/create-bar-chart-graph-using-mpandroidchart-library/)

```
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

      import com.android.volley.Request;
      import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
      import com.android.volley.Response;
      import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
      import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
      import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

      import org.json.JSONArray;
      import org.json.JSONException;
      import org.json.JSONObject;

      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
      import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
      import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
      import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
      import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     TextView textView;
     RequestQueue requestQueue;

     BarChart chart ;
     ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
     ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
     BarDataSet Bardataset ;
     BarData BARDATA ;

      @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewData);


    chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

    BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();

    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

    AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();

    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");

    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);

    Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    chart.setData(BARDATA);

    chart.animateY(3000);
    AddValuesToBARENTRY();

         requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest
   =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,  http://**/**/barGraphData2.php", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("result");
             for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
             JSONObject result= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 String std1= result.getString("std1");
                 String std2= result.getString("std2");
                 String std3= result.getString("std3");
                 String std4= result.getString("std4");
                 String std5= result.getString("std5");
                 String std6= result.getString("std6");
                 String std7= result.getString("std7");


                 // View data in text few
                 textView.setText(
                          "bar 1 -->"+std1+"\n"
                         +"bar 2 -->"+std2+"\n"
                         +"bar 3 -->"+std3+"\n"
                         +"bar 4 -->"+std4+"\n"
                         +"bar 5 -->"+std5+"\n"
                         +"bar 6 -->"+std6+"\n"
                         +"bar 7 -->"+std7+"\n"
                               );
                //call method  to use information in  barGraph 
       AddValuesToBARENTRY (std1, std2, std3, std4, std5, std6);

             }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"there is error bro",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ) ;
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}


public void AddValuesToBARENTRY(String std1,String std2,String std3,String std4,String std5,String std6){
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std1), 0));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std2), 1));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std3), 2));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std4), 3));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std5), 4));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(std6), 5));

}

public void AddValuesToBarEntryLabels(){

    BarEntryLabels.add("January");
    BarEntryLabels.add("February");
    BarEntryLabels.add("March");
    BarEntryLabels.add("April");
    BarEntryLabels.add("May");
    BarEntryLabels.add("June");

}
}
```

Comment: AddValuesToBARENTRY(); sets empty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the wiki of the [Github Link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data), you need to refresh the bar chart after data is set.

try

```
//call method  to use information in  barGraph 
AddValuesToBARENTRY (std1, std2, std3, std4, std5, std6);
// refresh the bar chart
chart.invalidate();
```